# Updating a contact given its name does not work

Tags: java, android

I have some issue when update given_name Contact, my code:

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastname);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstname);
    ops.add(builder.build());
```

Initial name : John Smith
1st case : change given_name with Joh, Result Success
2nd case : change given_name with Johny, Result Fail

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " and " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstname)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastname)
        .build());
```